# Fabric showing only loading on Missing DSYMs section

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am using fabric crashlytics to track crashes. Earlier it was working but now it is showing only loading while clicking on Missing `DSYMs` sections.

[image]

If any one come across this issue, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here.

We had a temporary bug on this page, it's since been patched and fixed. Should be working for everybody now.

Incident status for reference: http://status.fabric.io/incidents/p9hv7yd0562y